# How do you set up unit tests without Karma?

Tags: angularjs

I'm following the [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). Because I want to learn to use Angular in an ASP.NET project, I'm straying from the tutorial. I'm having problems writing unit tests. From what I understand, AngularJS uses Jasmine for unit tests. So I took out the standard HTML page I use for Jasmine tests.

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.1.3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/jasmine.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/unittests/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/unittests/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/unittests/boot.js"></script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
@Styles.Render("~/SiteCSS")
@Scripts.Render("~/SiteScripts")

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="~/Scripts/unittests/les1tests.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this fails the AngularJS test in step 2 of the tutorial:

```
describe('PhoneListCtrl', function () {

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function () {
        var scope = {},
        ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

        expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    });

});
```

Which wouldn't work. I fixed it by adding angular-mocks.js to my test page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/SiteCSS")
@Scripts.Render("~/SiteScripts")
<script src="~/Scripts/unittests/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

An the first test passed. Then I ran into another problem. This test in step 3 wouldn't run:

```
describe('PhoneCat App', function () {

    describe('Phone list view', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            browser.get('app/index.html');
        });


        it('should filter the phone list as a user types into the search box', function () {

            var phoneList = element.all(by.repeater('phone in phones'));
            var query = element(by.model('query'));

            expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(3);

            query.sendKeys('nexus');
            expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(1);

            query.clear();
            query.sendKeys('motorola');
            expect(phoneList.count()).toBe(2);
        });

    });

});
```

And I'm getting a "ReferenceError: browser is not defined" error. All answers I see involve the Karma testrunner, which I am not using. What am I doing wrong? How do I get this test to work if I don't want to use Karma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing unit tests, typically run using Karma, and executed by the web browser, with end-to-end tests, written using the Protractor API.

Protractor, end-to-end tests are not run inside the browser. They use the Jasmine API but are executed by node.js. The node process starts a web browser and communicates with it using Selenium, and acts as a real user would do in front of your webapp.